# Linux: Apache can not delete file despite of sufficient permissions

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, access-denied, selinux

PHP script uploads archives on the web server and unzip them. Under some conditions I need to delete previously unzipped files. But apache can not delete the files because it get "Access denied" error despite of it has all the necessary permissions. I tried to delete them as 'apache' user manually and got the same error.

For example:

```
# ls -l
....
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache      46 янв 26 11:11 desktop.ini


# sudo -u apache rm desktop.ini
rm: невозможно удалить «desktop.ini»: Отказано в доступе
```

^^^ It means Access Denied

I can delete the files as 'root' user.
I thought that it can be by selinux restrictions. But selinux works in permissive mode:

```
# getenforce
Permissive
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the apache service is indeed running as username 'apache' as it is typically running as username 'www-data' however I am sure you most likely have checked this already.

the user 'apache' only has write/read permissions in your above post

however to delete a file you need write/execute permissions

give the user execute permissions

Comment: I checked httpd.conf, all correct (User apache, Group apache, it's CentOs 7). Added 'x' permission -rwxrwxr--. 1 apache apache      46 янв 26 11:11 desktop.ini. - All the same, access denied